# DB2 server installation via command line

Tags: centos, db2

I need to install DB2 (DB2 Advanced Enterprise Server Edition 10.5) in a centos linux VM. I am not allowed to do a X11 forwarding.
Is it possible to install DB2 server via command prompt?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Can you forward any links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install without a GUI using `db2_install`. It has a help option and is documented in the [DB2 Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0023669.html). The command is located in the top directory of your install files.

Comment: You can also use db2setup with a response file.  See the sample response files (names like `db2server.rsp`, `db2rtcl.rsp`, etc) with the install media in the `db2/PLATFORM/samples` directory.